# how to access image stored on firebase cloud storage

Tags: reactjs, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage

So i have managed to store my image on firebase storage from my node js backend and storing the link to that image in my database also but when I try to go to the URL where my image is stored I get the error in the image attached so looked it up and tried changing my rules for my storage to allow read from all but still get that error does anyone know why as I want to display this image on the client side of my app but it doesn't work right now as access isn't allowed do you need to give the token to access it or is there anyway that the rules can be modified that any user can view (so read) but only authed can write?

error message image:

[image]

error message:

> Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the
> Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied
> on resource (or it may not exist).

storage rules:

```
rules_version = '2';

// Craft rules based on data in your Firestore database
// allow write: if firestore.get(
//    /databases/(default)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin;
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {


    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
    }
  }
```

}

server side code to upload the image (this works)

```
async function uploadProfilePicture(path) {
  console.log("inside profile pciture func path = ", path);
  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
  const uploadedFile = await bucket.upload(path);
  console.log("uploaded file = ", uploadedFile);
  const [metadata] = await uploadedFile[0].getMetadata();
  console.log("upload file metadata = ", metadata);
  const downloadUrl = uploadedFile[0].getSignedUrl({
    action: "read",
    expires: "01-01-2028",
  });
  console.log("download url = ", downloadUrl[0]);
  return metadata.selfLink;
}
```

client side to view the profile pic:

```
return (
    <div className="bg-gray-100 p-4">
{medallionProfile.lastName}</h2>
        <img style={{height: '300px', width: 'auto'}} src={medallionProfile.profilePicture}></img>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: What is the error?  Copy and paste it into the question.  Also you should know that signed URLs aren't affected by security rules at all. Rules only affect the way that that reads and writes work with the Firebase SDKs.

Comment: @DougStevenson sorry about that I added it to the question now